# Order of EJB injection lookup for multiple possibilities

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

Having multiple implementations of a @Local Interface:

```
@Local
public interface LocalInterface {
}

@Stateless
public class FirstLocalImpl implements LocalInterface {
}

@Stateless
public class SecondLocalImpl implements LocalInterface {
}
```

and an @EJB Injection in a third bean:

```
public class Foo {
   @EJB
   LocalInterface local;
}
```

Which implementation is chosen to be injected into Foo::local and how is the order defined? Note that no ejb-jar.xml is specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get a detailed error at deployment time, telling you that there are two implementations of the same interface. To solve this you have to specify the bean name:

```
@EJB(beanName="FirstLocalImpl")
LocalInterface local;
```